# How to read rows above and below a specified value

Tags: r, read.table

I have some data on a table to be read (currently using read.table), but the minimum value that I have on the table is 27, and the maximum value is 1000.
I need to set the `read.table` to only read values >180 and <800. My data is too large to go by hand (700k+ rows). Is there any way to do it?

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
data1 <- read.table('cn_EP27_L1.sizes')
  names(data1) <- 'sizes1' 
  data1
```

Table content:
[image: Table content]

Comment: How many columns are present.  Is this condition based on a specific column

Comment: Hi! It's only one column. 

I just don't want the rows with values under 180 and above 800 to be read. (I added a picture of the table for more clarification)

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I am running RStudio on a remote server using Ubuntu 16.04.7.

Comment: if on windows, take a look at `data.table::fread()` in combination with the `cmd-argument` using the windows-command `findstr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` with `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(pipe("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\" \"} {if ($1 >180 && $1 < 800) print $0}' cn_EP27_L1.sizes.txt"))
```

Comment: With that line R returns with an error "no lines available in input"

Comment: @iagosch there was a syntax error in that.  It is now working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try package `sqldf`, function `read.csv.sql`. It allows to filter the rows (or columns) with SQL statements.

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "select * from file where V1 > 180 and V1 < 800"
df2 <- read.csv.sql(file = "test_read.txt", sql, sep = " ")
```

After testing,

```
unlink("test_read.txt")
```

**Test data file**

```
n <- 700e3
set.seed(2021)
df1 <- matrix(sample(27:1000, 2*n, TRUE), ncol = 2)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
write.table(df1, "test_read.txt", sep = " ", 
            quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```